# Is there any way to get mobile carrier activate date or first call date programmatically in Android/iOS?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, device, carrier

I need mobile carrier information in phone.

In Android Samsung Galaxy, after os version 7(Nougat), there is first call date in System Setting app > Device Info. And some secret codes for hidden menu have field named 'OD' that mobile carrier activate date(I think this code not working in these days phone. Code was '*#248569#').

So,

1. Is there any way to get above information programmatically in both mobile os, Android and iOS?
2. Or if i can't get above information, is there any way to get mobile carrier activate date or first call date programmatically in both mobile os, Android and iOS?
3. Or if i can't get information programmatically, is there any way to get that information in my device(like settings, secret code for hidden menu, or etc)?

Any help would be appreciate.